# How to declare statements using 'this' as static?

Tags: java, android, static

I have an activity named Gridactivity,

```
public String readFile(int file)
    {
        try{
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(file);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
        System.out.print(is.available());
        System.out.print(is.available());

        while (is.read(buffer) != -1)   
            ;
        String text = new String(buffer);
    return(text);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String Ex=" ";
            return(Ex);
        }
    }
```

followed with a file reading method-readFile() this reads the file from the raw folder and save it in a string and return it. Here now i need to make this readFile as static. But here 'this' in `InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(file);` statement is non-static.
How to make it static function so I can access this from other classes and activities?

Comment: Then How will you call this static readFile() function ? You need to use statement `InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(file)` somewhere else in your program. You can store this is in some other variable which is accessible at both places caller function and also inside readFile() or more easily define readFile as readFile(InputStream is) and pass the `is`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

An instance method is executed within the context of an instance of its class (an instance of Gridactivity, for instance). `this` is the keyword that refers to this context. A static method doesn't have such a context, so what would `this` mean?

Your two options are to make the static method non static, or to make any methods you call from a static method also static, which means whatever information you need from your `this` instance will have to be explicitly passed in as arguments. So, instead of:

```
void myInstanceMethod() {
    System.out.println(this.myInt);
}
```

You'd have to do something like:

```
void myStaticMethod(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can never use `this` in a static context as `this` points to an instance object.

One way you could achieve static method is to pass `Resources` as argument, as follows:

```
public static String readFile(Resources resources, int file) { ... }
```

And, eventually,

```
InputStream is = resources.openRawResource(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is a pass a context.

```
public static String readFile(Context context, int file) {
    try{
        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(file);
[...]
```

And here is the call of my code:

```
String content=GridActivity.readFile(this, 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, try

```
public static String readFile(Context context, int file)
```

and use it here:

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(file);
```

Basically you pass the variable as your parameter.

(`getResources()` is a method for [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) class).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't understand the concept of static class members.

Static class members (variables, methods) are class level i.e. not tight to instance where ordinary fields and methods are tight to instance. You can use static members from non-static context but not vice versa.

Comment: If he would understand everything, he wouldn't ask. Resources are by their nature global thingies. That we could use them from instances only is unnatural. So, we need a workaround or some of them. Two were proposed here. Where is yours? :-)

Comment: Man, take it easy, I am only java developer, not Android and I saw he is struggling with static, that's all :)

Answer (score 0):

static members and methods can be accessed mainly with Class name and also with object name.

keyword **this** means current object.

If you don't know about static please read information at this [lnik](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

Comment: Don't be arrogant - it is the very natural question. Resources are global by their nature. So, why can we address them in instances only? It is not class/instance problem, it is android specific problem.

Comment: @Gangnus I am not talking about the code posted here. see the title, it must be relevant to the question message body. am i correct or not ?

Comment: I would rather suppose that the author hasn't expressed his thought correctly enough, than he doesn't know about something. BTW, your answer is not absolutely clean, either - it took time to me to understand your first sentence. Better use class-instance terminology than class-object. Because Object IS A CLASS :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, BUT:
You can declare static variables and load values into them in the onCreate function.  THERE you can use **this**.

Or make some initialization function

```
initAllStaticStuff(Context context){
    someStaticVariable=context.getResources...
}
```

called from onCreate as

```
initAllStaticStuff(this).
```

So you can load all needed resources into static variables and use them later.